# Tengo problemas con try y except

Tags: python

```
sh=float(input("Enter hours:"))
Sr= float(input("Enter rate:"))
Try:
   If sh>40:
      Xh=(sh*sr)
      except:
         Print("Error, please enter numeric input")
         Xy=(sh-40)*(sr*0.5)
         Xz=(xh*xy)
         else:
            Xz=(sh*sr)
            Print("pay",xz)
```

Tengo que esté programa es pago de horas trabajadas.

Tiene que tener una salida de `475`, `hours=45` y `rate=10`, pero tengo problema con `except`, tiene que dar un print de error cuando no se ingresa un número, necesito ayuda estoy llevando un curso en Python y no entiendo xq no corre el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar tú código en formato texto no como imagen, para eso tiene la opción ejemplo de código {} en la barra de opciónes de pregunta, para facilitar al que te ayude de podes copiar y pegar tú codigo.

Comment: La indentación está mal. El except debe estar a la misma altura que el try. Y por otro lado ¿el else que se ve a qué if corresponde? no puede ser al del principio, pues aparece un except por el medio. En definitiva, esta mal anidado y no tengo claro qué pretendías en tealidad.

Answer (score 2):

lo primero es la indentación, python es sensible a los tabuladores y el `try` y `except` deben estar en la misma columna, esto es porque python no usa algun caracter para delimitar el inicio y fin de algún bloque como podria ser un `while`, un `for`, un `if` y su `else`(que tambien tienes mal indentado) o en este caso el `try`, `except`, en vez de ello se basa en el numero de espacios que existen.

En este ejemplo se ve claramente el uso de indentación que te comento y un ejemplo sencillo del `try`

```
try:
    10/0
except:
    print ("No se puede dividir sobre 0")
```

de lo contario te generara un error de sintaxis.

Ahora bien, el error que controla el bloque `try` debería ser al momento que el usuario ingrese un dato y python quiera convertirlos a float, por lo cual tus input tendrian que estar dentro del `try`.

```
try:
    sh = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
    sh = float(input("Enter Rate:"))
except:
    print("Error please enter a valid value")
```

De lo demás no veo que tengas problemas, espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias voy probar tus sugerencias